# How to redirected php page after generate word file

Tags: javascript, php

I have generated word file after updates records. Updates records and generated word file is fine but I can not redirect another php page after generate word file.

### PHP Code

// in update.php

code with update query and

redirect in script after updating a query -

```
window.location = "quotation_word.php?quot_id=$quotation_idshow";

// in quotation_word.php 

// generating word file in php with -<br/>

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

// display code in word file

// generating word file is fine but
// Now, I want to go another php page. So what will I do for redirecting to other page after generate word file
```

please help me.

Comment: Did you try header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); in  quotation_word.php?

Comment: You are passing the word doc to the output buffer so this might not be possible with the PHP header() function. Why not do this in a pop up window or hidden iframe so you can redirect the page with JS?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Or if you want to redirect by javascript:

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://example.com/';</script>";
```